# Apache Common Logging

Tags: java, apache-commons-logging

let's begin with the default code of logging between two classes :

**Implementation:**

*Class A:*

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.cc.B;

public class A {

    public static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(A.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logger.info("Entering application.");
        B b = new B();
        b.doIt();
        logger.info("Exiting application.");
    }
}
```

*Class B:*

```
package com.cc;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class B {
    public static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(B.class);

       public void doIt() {
         log.debug("Did it");
       }
}
```

**Execution:**

```
16 mars 2012 09:31:35 com.cc.A main
INFO: Entering application.
16 mars 2012 09:31:35 com.cc.B doIt
INFO: Did it
16 mars 2012 09:31:35 com.cc.A main
INFO: Exiting application.
```

in the B class, replacing `public static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(B.class);` to `public static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(A.class);` has no effect to the log of the application.

how can i log only into the class A logger ?

Comment: Post your log4j.properties, btw.: what do you mean by only log into the class A logger? It makes sense to know where your log-messages are originating from - what do you want to achieve?

Comment: this is i want to have : 
`16 mars 2012 09:31:35 com.cc.A main
INFO: Entering application.
16 mars 2012 09:31:35 **com.cc.A** doIt
INFO: Did it
16 mars 2012 09:31:35 com.cc.A main
INFO: Exiting application.`

Comment: Since there is also a method name I think the com.cc.B is automatically discovered and part of the address of the method calling the logger. The class parameter to `getLog` is AFAIK just convenience and convention, so that you can easily control logging level by packages. (Log DEBUG in package com.example.foo but only INFO in package com.example.bar)

Comment: @quaylar i didn't use the log4j i used common logging

Answer (score 0):

First: I agree with quaylar that you do want to know from where your log message originates so I would say that this is bad practice in any code review.

Second: I think you should always use slf4j so that you can bridge all the logging frameworks of all 3rd party libraries you use to your preferred logging framework.

Having said that:
You can achieve what you want to achieve if you use log4j instead if you make sure that B instantiates the same logger as A.

A simpler solution would be to just use a static import of the logger defined in A into B:

```
import static com.cc.A.logger;
```

and then use it in B:

```
public void doIt() {
    logger.debug("Did it");
}
```

Comment: I just realized that the static import will not compile so that's not  a working solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I get this output:

```
2012-03-17 18:13:37,859 INFO  main cc.A Entering application.
2012-03-17 18:13:37,861 DEBUG main cc.A Did it
2012-03-17 18:13:37,861 INFO  main cc.A Exiting application.
```

With this code for A:

```
package com.cc;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.cc.B;

public class A {
    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Entering application.");
        B b = new B();
        b.doIt();
        logger.info("Exiting application.");
    }
}
```

And this code for B:

```
package com.cc;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class B {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(A.class);
    public void doIt() {
        logger.debug("Did it");
    }
}
```

And this config for log4j:

```
log4j.rootCategory      =   DEBUG, A1
log4j.appender.A1       =   org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout                    = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern  = %d %-5p %t %c{2} %m%n
```

But I can't help wondering if you're really after having something identifying the application in each log row? In that case just add the application name to the log pattern:

```
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern  = %d %-5p %t %c{2} MyApplicationName %m%n
```

If you then changed back B to init logger like this:

```
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(B.class);
```

You would have this output instead:

```
2012-03-17 18:13:37,859 INFO  main cc.A MyApplicationName Entering application.
2012-03-17 18:13:37,861 DEBUG main cc.B MyApplicationName Did it
2012-03-17 18:13:37,861 INFO  main cc.A MyApplicationName Exiting application.
```

Comment: thank you for your help but i used Apache common logging not log4j and they are not the same